# Upgrading Spring 3.2.3 from Spring 3.1.0, ConversionNotSupportedException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am upgrading from Spring 3.1.0 to Spring 3.2.3 with my WebApp, and I cannot figure out why I am getting a 500 error.  Here is a snippet of my code:

```
@Controller("myController")
@RequestMapping("/")
@SessionAttributes({"myObject"})
public class MyController {
@RequestMapping(value="/submit.action", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submit(
        @Validated @ModelAttribute("myObject") MyObject myObject
        , RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes
        , BindingResult bindingResult) 
{
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                mav.setViewName("redirect:/first.do");
                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errors", new HashMap<String, Object>(bindingResult.getModel());
                return mav;
            }
    mav.setViewName("redirect:/next.do");
    mav.addObject("myObject", myObject);

    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/first.do", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView show(
        @ModelAttribute("errors") HashMap<String, Object> errors) 
{
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

            if(errors.size() > 0){
                mav.addAllObjects(errors);
            }
    mav.setViewName("first.jsp");
    mav.addObject("myObject", new MyObject());

    return mav;
}
}
```

MyObject is a simple POJO with a java.util.List property, and it implements Serializable. For some reason, the DispatcherServlet pukes with the following error after the ModelAndView is returned:

```
[12/4/13 12:33:53:177 EST] 00000030 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[myDispatcherServlet]: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 500
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:626)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:656)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.sendError(SRTServletResponse.java:1236)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.sendError(SRTServletResponse.java:1210)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.sendServerError(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:309)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleConversionNotSupported(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:297)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:130)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1148)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:985)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
at gov.treas.publicdebt.ie.web.filter.MyDispatcher.doDispatch(MyDispatcher.java:15)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
at gov.treas.publicdebt.ie.web.filter.MyFilter.doFilter(MyFilter.java:67)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3751)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1690)
```

Digging deeper, I found this to be the cause:

```
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'MyObject' to required type 'java.lang.String'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [MyObject] to required type [java.lang.String]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

I cannot figure out why it is attempting to convert MyObject to a String. I have not had any issues using Spring 3.1.0, but switching to Spring 3.2.3 has forced my DispatcherServlet to try and convert MyObject.  I would really prefer to not have to register a bunch of custom editors for my POJOs. Does anyone have any ideas?

**IN ADDITION**
The exception is being caught in the doDispatch method of the DispatchServlet class. In the catch block, ex.printStackTrace() yielded the following result:

```
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'MyObject' to required type 'java.lang.String'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [MyObject] to required type [java.lang.String]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:71)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:39)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:589)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributesModelMap.formatValue(RedirectAttributesModelMap.java:77)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributesModelMap.addAttribute(RedirectAttributesModelMap.java:69)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributesModelMap.addAllAttributes(RedirectAttributesModelMap.java:105)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributesModelMap.addAllAttributes(RedirectAttributesModelMap.java:34)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.method.support.ModelAndViewContainer.addAllAttributes(ModelAndViewContainer.java:212)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ModelAndViewMethodReturnValueHandler.handleReturnValue(ModelAndViewMethodReturnValueHandler.java:76)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:69)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at gov.treas.publicdebt.ie.web.filter.MyDispatcher.doDispatch(MyDispatcher.java:15)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at gov.treas.publicdebt.ie.web.filter.UserTokenFilter.doFilter(UserTokenFilter.java:67)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:895)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:620 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:636 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:636 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:636 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:636 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:636 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:636 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:636 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:636 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:636 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1690)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:636 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [MyObject] to required type [java.lang.String]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
[12/4/13 14:22:28:636 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:264)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:636 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:93)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:636 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:61)
[12/4/13 14:22:28:636 EST] 0000004e SystemErr     R     ... 48 more
```

UPDATED: Added additional code to better define the use case. My mistake...

Comment: Also, I ALWAYS pick a correct answer if an adequate one is provided :D

Comment: We would need to see the full stack trace.

Comment: Didn't I already provide it above....?

Comment: You stated _Digging deeper, I found this to be the cause:_ I want all the traces that were dug up.

Comment: Updated with all I have

Comment: It appears that, since you specified a redirect, Spring is using a RedirectAttributesModelMap, which did not exist in 3.1.0.  The redirect attributes map separates attributes into "flash" attributes, which are put into the redirected request, and standard attributes which are used to form the redirect URL.  All standard attributes have to be convertible to String.  This suggests a hacky way to fix the problem would be `((RedirectAttributesModelMap) mav.getModelMap()).addFlashAttribute("myobject", new MyObject());` but there must be a better way.

Comment: @Pace I think you are onto something. In the method mapped to first.do, I am using RedirectAttributes. I bet removing them will work... My mistake for unknowingly omitting the relevant code!

Comment: @pace Thanks a lot! In my case I used RedirectAttributes but didn't do redirect.